# Cannot read property '...' of undefined

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I'm building an Ionic application with Native Google Maps and Firebase. I have this Firebase structure:

[image]

I'm trying to get these properties by their ids. So, I created a provider and a function `getLocalDetail()`:

```
import { ... };

@Injectable()

export class LocalProvider {

  constructor(public afd: AngularFireDatabase) {

  }

  getLocalDetail(localId): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.afd.list('/local/'+localId).subscribe(data => {
        resolve(data);
      })
    })
  }

}
```

And I'm trying to show these properties in my page:

```
import { ... };

@IonicPage()

@Component()

export class LocalPage {

  public localRef: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;

  constructor(..., public localProvider: LocalProvider) {

  }

 ionViewDidEnter(){
    this.localProvider.getLocalDetail(this.navParams.get('localId')).then(data => {
      this.localRef = data;   
    });
  }

}
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<p>Latitude: <strong>{{localRef.latitudeLocal}}</strong></p>
<p>Longitude: <strong>{{localRef.longitudeLocal}}</strong></p>
```

But the result is the error `Cannot read property 'latitudeLocal' of undefined`. I believe that my function is not retrieving data... Anyone can help me?

Comment: If the html renders before the promise resolves, then localRef will indeed be undefined and trying to access properties will throw an error. Angular lets you use the elvis operator to check for undefined or null values. Have you tried {{localRef?.latitudeLocal}} and {{localRef?.longitudeLocal}} in your template?

Comment: asynchronous code is always fun

Comment: @programmingforfun yes, I tried. The error no longer appears but the data doesn't show.